# How to increase power of wifi adapter

Tags: wireless

How can I increase the tx power of my wifi adapter?
I want to increase it more than the limit (15)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can increase power with this command`sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower 20` but please do it in small increments if you set it to high you could destroy your device. Some devices will not accept higher power settings. You can set it to auto with `sudo iwconfig wlan0 rate auto` replace wlan0 with your connections name in `iwconfig` it is most like wlan0 or eth1.

Comment: if the parameter is not applicable you can try re-compile some wifi stuff: https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/set-your-wi-fi-cards-tx-power-higher-than-30-dbm-0149606/

Answer (score 2):

consider of installing a repeater or external router with good or directed antena. Increasing power is not recommended and not welcome by other users of other hotspots in your area as you will increase the wifi noise. Others can afterwards increase power too and nobody will have a good signal.