# Not able to discover all avilable wifi networks in ubuntu 14.04 & weak signal strength

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, broadcom

I am able to see only a single network, which is showing a very weak signal strength and I'm not able to connect to that too. Please find details below.

```
~$ cat /etc/*release* | grep -i distrib
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"

$ lspci | grep -i bcm
08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)

$  lshw -c network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 9c:ad:97:cb:e8:9d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.141 (r415941) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:18 memory:b5500000-b5507fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 08
       serial: 8c:dc:d4:6e:a2:f3
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:60 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b5404000-b5404fff memory:b5400000-b5403fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: usb0
       serial: e2:23:b0:d2:86:80
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.181 link=yes multicast=yes
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.


$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no


$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 8c:dc:d4:6e:a2:f3  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1777 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1777 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:171412 (171.4 KB)  TX bytes:171412 (171.4 KB)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e2:23:b0:d2:86:80  
          inet addr:192.168.42.181  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e023:b0ff:fed2:8680/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10720 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:1
          TX packets:12968 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5448768 (5.4 MB)  TX bytes:2178541 (2.1 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:ad:97:cb:e8:9d  
          inet6 addr: fe80::9ead:97ff:fecb:e89d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:2664
          TX packets:66 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1393 (1.3 KB)  TX bytes:15322 (15.3 KB)
          Interrupt:18 

~$ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
bcmwl-kernel-source is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 385 not upgraded.
```

Kindly help me to resolve this issue with Wi-fi. Please comment here if you need additional information.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? I've often found with unstable/poor wifi that its likely a driver issue, as booting into another OS on the same hardware the wifi would work fine, check /var/log/messages & dmesg for wifi issues.

Comment: Thanks for your comment -@Grizly. i did`t get any error message. As you said, previously wi-fi was working fine with Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution: 
you can try to increase the power of the wifi adapter, as it written [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328418/how-to-increase-power-of-wifi-adapter). 
(But be careful.)

Answer (score 0):

Had a problem with weak and unstable WIFI signal on my Asus K555LN using Broadcom 43142 card on Linux Mint 17.1.
It appears to be fixed by just running this command, as suggested in this thread [Drivers for Broadcom BCM43142 on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459654/drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr)

```
# (sudo rmmod b43 ; sudo rmmod bcma ; sudo rmmod wl ; sudo modprobe wl ; sudo modprobe lib80211_crypt_tkip)
```